# Can't attach event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, nested-lists

I'm [using this plugin](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable) to manage hierarchical data. Now all I want to do is to listen for `onclick` event. Yeah, that sounds *stupid*, but it does not work at all!

The problem, is that elements **do exists**, but its not possible to attach a listener to them!

```
        $('#nestable2').find('.dd-handle, .dd-item').on('click', function(e){
            alert("Test");
        });
```

Has anyone faced this problem?

**UPDATE**

- Yes, its inside DOM Ready
- `$('#nestable2').find('.dd-handle, .dd-item').length` does not return 0, but a greater value
- I've tried both event delegation and "regular" event listeners

Comment: What is the value of `$('#nestable2').find('.dd-handle, .dd-item').length`?

Comment: Does the selector match anything?

Comment: @Halcyon as I said they do *exists* and their `.length` is more than 0 !!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Since the `.length` property is greater than 0, looks like it does

Comment: I agree with you that this code should work but as you said, it's not. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: @Halcyon Nope, they do appear before !

Comment: Are the elements appended after DOM ready? If so use a delegated event handler: `$('#nestable2').on('click', '.dd-handle, .dd-item', function(e) { ... });`. Can you post an example of the problem in a fiddle. All anyone can post at the moment is guesses.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Actually elements are generated via server's side language and when document is rendered, all elements are already there! So both should work : regular event listener and delegation

Comment: R u placed the code into $(document).ready() function

Comment: Have you tried the direct event assign? `$('#nestable2').click(function() { alert("Test"); });`

Comment: @LcSalazar Yes. Event listeners and event delegation. Both don't work

Comment: You should replicate your issue on jsFiddle

Comment: Have you checked for other javascript errors that might be stopping your script execution?

Comment: How exactly are you testing the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your event is being registered to the elements. BUT the problem is the 3rd party code you are using. Somewhere along the line their are overridding or cancelling the click action.

If you change your `click` to `mousedown`, you will see your alert so that proves the event is being registered.

Running this on the test page

```
    $('#nestable2').find('.dd-handle, .dd-item').on('click', function(e){
        alert("CLICK");
    }).on('mousedown', function(e){
        alert("mousedown");
    });
```

I see the mousedown, not not the click.

Comment: Are you sure that a preventDefault on a mousedown prevents a click event from occurring?

Comment: @Rui It shouldn't AFAIK and can see: http://jsfiddle.net/5MRLg/  As i see it, the plugin is removing element from DOM on mousedown, using some kind of helper/clone. But then ya, using mousedown instead of click would work i guess

Comment: I'm using chrome, and I see the alert, so the click happens for me even when prevent default is called on mousedown

Comment: @Rui same here on chrome

Comment: The problem is still with the 3rd party cancelling the click action or overwriting it. Too busy to actually walk the code.

Comment: `Running this on the test page` But that's because of modal behaviour of alert() method, click event is then not fired.

Comment: well..... it there any way to trigger `click` event? not `change` nor `mousedown`??

Comment: @A.Wolff I also ran it as console and it does not run also. So the alert makes ZERO difference.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, i didn't saw you were referring to the plugin, i was thinking you were referring to `e.preventDefault on mousedown`

Answer (score 1):

If you are absolutely sure that `$('#nestable2').find('.dd-handle, .dd-item')` actually returns elements, what might actually be happening is that you are deregistering the click handlers for that element somewhere else. That will look something like this:

`$('.dd-handle, .dd-item').off("click")`

It can even be more obscure, for example `$("button").off("click")`

If your codebase is large this can be hard to find.

A neat trick you can do is to take advantage of jQuery's special events.
You can add a method that runs each time an event handler is added or removed and put a debugger statement in there, and finally check where it happens in the codebase (using for example the dev tools in chrome and checking the call stack)

Here's how you can do it (add this as soon as possible in the page, just after you load jquery):

```
$.event.special.click = {
  add: function(handlerObj){ debugger; },
  remove: function(handlerObj){ debugger; }
};
```

The handlerObj contains
  -type
   The type of event, in this case it will be click
  -namespaces
   a string with all the namespaces provided on "on", if any
  -selector
  -guid
  -data
  -handler

Here's a good resource that explains [special events](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Don't rule out events handlers that were added, they might have call [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) and that way be responsible for the handlers you exepect to run, not running.